# Find element that is clicked change siblings

Tags: jquery

I would like to change all elements in a list except the one that is clicked. I suppose I need to determine what is actually clicked and then change it's siblings? How do I find which element is clicked?

```
<ul>
    <li><h4 class="span1"><a href="#" class="sort" data-sort="ID">ID<i class="icon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h4></li>
    <li><h4 class="span2"><a href="#" class="sort" data-sort="Type">Type<i class="icon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h4></li>
    <li><h4 class="span3"><a href="#" class="sort" data-sort="Task">Task<i class="icon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h4></li>
    <li><h4 class="span8"><a href="#" class="sort" data-sort="Project">Project<i class="icon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h4></li>
    <li><h4 class="span3a"><a href="#" class="sort" data-sort="DueDate">Urgency<i class="icon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h4></li>
    <li><h4 class="span3 last"><a href="#" class="sort" data-sort="Created">Date Created<i class="icon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h4></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('.sort').click(function () {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);

    if($(this).data('clicked')) {
        $('i', this).toggleClass('icon-arrow-down').toggleClass('icon-arrow-up');
    } 
    else {
        $('.sort i').siblings().removeClass('icon-arrow-up').addClass('icon-arrow-down');
    }
});
```

---

Answer:

```
$('.sort').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('i').removeClass('icon-arrow-up').addClass('icon-arrow-down');
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-arrow-down icon-arrow-up');
});
```

Comment: You set `$(this).data('clicked', true)` and then test it in the very next line? What for?

Comment: What is the behavior you *want* to see? Everything should have `icon-arrow-down` unless it was the last item clicked, in which case it should have `icon-arrow-up`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `$(this)` represents the anchor element clicked, `siblings()` can't access the other `li` elements. Instead, look for the siblings of the element two levels above, like this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().siblings().removeClass("foo");
```

Or change the markup so that you're targeting the `li` instead of the anchor contained within.

Comment: Your right. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the solution above using your direction.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
$('.sort').click(function (e) {
    $('.sort').not(e.currentTarget).css({
        color: 'red'
    });
    return false
});​
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/th3KV/

your code:

```
$('.sort').click(function (e) {

    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-arrow-down icon-arrow-up');

    $('.sort').not(e.currentTarget).each(function(){
        $(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-arrow-up').addClass('icon-arrow-down');
    });
    return false
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.sort').click(function() {
    $(".sort i").removeClass('icon-arrow-up').addClass('icon-arrow-down');
    $("i", this).toggleClass('icon-arrow-down icon-arrow-up')
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BHtw5/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each a tag is unique by the data-sort attribute as it seems in the above sample:

```
$('.sort').click(function () {

$("ul li").each($.proxy(function(index, item) {
if ($("a", item).data("sort") !== $(this).data("sort") {
  //different element than the one clicked
}
}, this));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is relatively easy to read and understand:

```
$('a.sort').click(function () {
    $("i", this)
        .toggleClass('icon-arrow-down')
        .toggleClass('icon-arrow-up')
        .closest("li")
        .siblings()
        .find("i")
        .removeClass('icon-arrow-up')
        .addClass('icon-arrow-down');
});​
```